# Magento | Apply a custom price after it has already been applied (Cart Update)

Tags: php, magento, product

I've been applying a custom price to a product using the following method:

- Used the event "checkout_cart_product_add_after" and created a function for it respectively.
- In that function, I used the method $item->setCustomPrice($value).

The product is added to cart sucessfuly with the custom price and everything is correct. Including the Tax applied and the totals.
However, when I update that same product quantity in the cart and set another custom price, things don't go so well.

I'm using the event "checkout_cart_save_after", doing the exact same thing I mentioned before and I'm getting the following problems:

- If I choose the following Tax option on Magento's backoffice "Display Product Prices In Catalog: Including Tax", the price isn't modified whatsoever.
- If I don't include Tax on Catalog Product Prices, the price is updated. However, the totals are still using the old custom price.

I don't know if I'm using the wrong event for this. At the moment I feel like my only solution is to remove the product and add it again to the cart with a new custom price. Which I believe, isn't the right way.

Thanks in advance to everyone who took time to look at this question.
If I'm not clear with my problem I'm glad to clarify any questions.

*edit*

I'll add a few more details that might help:

```
FOREACH($observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() AS $item){
  $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();

  $discountValue = 20; //This will be a custom value that I load with a Web Service

  $value = $productPrice - ($productPrice * $discountValue / 100);

  $item->setCustomPrice($value);
  $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($value);
}
```

This works on my first Custom Price update, not on my cart update as mentioned before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use both observer event checkout_cart_product_add_after and checkout_cart_update_items_after

checkout_cart_update_items_after this event fired when you update qty in cart So you need to use this event also.

Comment: Using the checkout_cart_update_items_after did the trick, thank you very much man. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue:

```
$item->setCustomPrice($value);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($value);
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing already in my first custom price update and my second custom price update. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue. Sorry I didn't mentioned it before, thanks for the help.

Comment: Added a few more details that might help.

Comment: The answer Sagar gave did the trick. Thank you a lot for the help : )